# Multiple Overloading in PHP

Tags: php, overloading

So I know I can use __callStatic() to allow for:

```
Example::test();
```

Too work... But what I was wondering if its possible to overload

```
Example::test->one()
Example::test->two()
```

Is this possible at all with PHP? If so does anyone have a working example?

Or does anyone know of a work around?

**Edit**

Thought I would add some more details on why am wanting to do this and its basically cause I have a API with has methods like api.method.function and want to build a simple script to interact with that api.

There is also some methods that are just api.method

Answer (score 4):

To quote the manual:

> __callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

So it doesn't work with properties - what you would need for your example to work as you described it is `__getStatic`. But, that doesn't exist.

The closest workaround that I can think of would be to use something like:

```
Example::test()->one();
Example::test()->two();
```

Where `test()` can be defined through `__callStatic` and it returns an object which has the methods `one` and `two`, or has `__call` defined.

EDIT:

Here's a small example (code hasn't been tested):

```
class ExampleTest {
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if ($name == 'one') {
            return 'one';
        }

        if ($name == 'two') {
            return 'two';
        }
    }
}

class Example {
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        if ($name == 'test') {
             // alternatively it could be return ExampleTest.getInstance() if you always want the same instance
            return new ExampleTest();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I spotted the __call function and that does mention Objects, but I wasn't sure if I could call it from within __callStatic and do what I needed. Not really thought of how I can test that yet...

Comment: But you wouldn't define it within `__callStatic`, you would define it on the class of the object that's returned by `test()`. If it's still unclear let me know and I'll add an example.

Comment: would this require predefined functions though? As I was hoping to do it all dynamically incase they ever changed, updated or removed method and functions out of the API.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "predefined". The example class uses `__call`, so you can call any methods on it, I've just written an example implementation for `one` and `two`, but you can do whatever you want inside it, based on the function name. EDIT: I think I understand, you are refering to the `test` method, right?

Comment: I will give this a try and see what happens for what I need.